# display a message when mongoDB collection is empty

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I have a notices section on my website which are stored in my Mongo Database. If the collection is empty, how would i display a message to say something like "No new notices"

I am looping this on my page using EJS my code is below.

```
        <% for (let notice of notices) {%>
            <p class="lead"><%= notice.noticeText %>
            <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can put a condition like so:

```
  <% if (!notices.length) {%>
    <p>desired text if no notice exists</p>
  <% } else { %>
    <% for (let notice of notices) {%>
        <p class="lead"><%= notice.noticeText %>
    <% } %>
  <% } %}
```